# slide does not comply with grid measurements

Tags: html, css, browser, media

The id c4 is occupying row 2 / span 1, and the slider should only be taking those row also because its measurements are going from row 2 / span 1, how would I put it into the div slidecourse correctly?

```css
#c4{
 background: white;

 z-index: 0;

 min-height: 200vh;
  min-width: 100vw;


 display: grid;

 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 20vh 60vh 5vh 15vh 15vh 85vh;
}

#c4 h1{
 grid-column: 1 / -1;
 grid-row: 1 / span 1;

 text-align: center;
 align-self: center;

 font-size: 2em;
}

#c4 .textoscurso{
 grid-column: 3 / span 3;
 grid-row: 2 / span 1;

 align-self: center;
}
#c4 .textoscurso p{
 align-self: center;
}

#c4 .slidecurso{
 grid-column: 7 / -1;
 grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

  #c4 .slidecurso slider{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #0ff;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
  }

  slider > *{
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #0ff;
   animation: slide 12s infinite;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  slide:nth-child(1){
   left: 0;
   animation-delay: -1s;
   background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }

  slide:nth-child(2){
   animation-delay: 2s;
   background-image: url(../img/curso.jpeg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }

  slide:nth-child(3){
   animation-delay: 5s;
   background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }

  slide:nth-child(4){
   left: 0;
   animation-delay: 8s;
   background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }


  slide p{
   font-family: Comfortaa;
   font-size: 70px;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 100px;
   color: #fff;
  }

  @keyframes slide{
   0%{left: 100%; width: 100%;}
   5%{left: 0%;}
   25%{left: 0%;}
   30%{left: -100%; width: 100%;}
   30.0001%{left: -100%; width: 0%;}
   100%{left: 100%; width: 0%;}
  }



#c4 .motivos{
 background: lightgray;

 grid-row: 4 / span 2;

 z-index: 10;
}

#c4 .moti-1{
 grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
#c4 .moti-2{
 grid-column: 5 / span 2;
}
#c4 .moti-3{
 grid-column: 8 / span 2;
}

#c4 .c4-2{
 grid-row: 5 / -1;
 grid-column: 1 / -1;

 background: black;
}
```

```html
<content id="c4">
    
    <h1>Venha aprender com a gente</h1>

    <div class="textoscurso">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus egestas posuere purus malesuada mattis.</div>

    <div class="slidecurso">
     <slider>
      <slide><p>Slide 1</p></slide>
      <slide><p>Slide 2</p></slide>
      <slide><p>Slide 3</p></slide>
      <slide><p>Slide 4</p></slide>
     </slider>
    </div>

    <div class="motivos moti-1"></div>
    <div class="motivos moti-2"></div>
    <div class="motivos moti-3"></div>

    <div class="c4-2"></div>

   </content>
```

The blue slide is not correctly sized as it should and then it goes beyond the limited heigth. 
I need it to be exactly inside row 2 / apan 1. Please

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative` to the slide element since the child are set to `position:absolute`. In this case the width/height will be relative to that element and you won't have overflow:

I have also removed some useless properties that may create issues (`min-width:100vw` for example):

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}

#c4 {
  background: white;
  min-height: 200vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 60vh 5vh 15vh 15vh 85vh;
}

#c4 h1 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#c4 .textoscurso {
  grid-column: 3 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  align-self: center;
}

#c4 .textoscurso p {
  align-self: center;
}

#c4 .slidecurso {
  grid-column: 7 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  position: relative;
}

#c4 .slidecurso slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0ff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

slider>* {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0ff;
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

slide:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  animation-delay: -1s;
  background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  background-image: url(../img/curso.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide:nth-child(4) {
  left: 0;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  background-image: url(../img/curso.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

slide p {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  5% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  30.0001% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}

#c4 .motivos {
  background: lightgray;
  grid-row: 4 / span 2;
  z-index: 10;
}

#c4 .moti-1 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}

#c4 .moti-2 {
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
}

#c4 .moti-3 {
  grid-column: 8 / span 2;
}

#c4 .c4-2 {
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<content id="c4">

  <h1>Venha aprender com a gente</h1>

  <div class="textoscurso">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus egestas posuere purus malesuada mattis.</div>

  <div class="slidecurso">
    <slider>
      <slide>
        <p>Slide 1</p>
      </slide>
      <slide>
        <p>Slide 2</p>
      </slide>
      <slide>
        <p>Slide 3</p>
      </slide>
      <slide>
        <p>Slide 4</p>
      </slide>
    </slider>
  </div>

  <div class="motivos moti-1"></div>
  <div class="motivos moti-2"></div>
  <div class="motivos moti-3"></div>

  <div class="c4-2"></div>

</content>
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain why 100vw could be a problem? I'm new to css and I'm used to using it in the sections next to 100vh.

Comment: @HenriqueRamos you are using block element so by default they will be full width, using 100vw will include the scroll bar width and you will have horizontal scroll in addition to the vertical one ... compare your code with mine and you will see that you have overflow on the right.

Comment: now i understand but this happens in the stackoverflow right?

Comment: @HenriqueRamos it will happen everywhere, here and also on your site

Comment: I am creating a site for study: http://www.henriqueramos.com.br/mae2 this is happening but does not appear because overflow x is hidden? obs: 
Not completely set for mobile

Comment: @HenriqueRamos yes exactly, you are hidding it use overflow:hidden. remove the overflow property and see

Comment: what you recommends for i use rather than 100vw?

Comment: @HenriqueRamos  nothing since it's useless or percentage value `100%`